# How to exclude PL/pgSQL functions in export?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pg-dump

I use following command to dump some structures from server' database to be able to create sample of data on my local hard drive.

```
pg_dump -h myserver.com -U product_user -s -f ./data/base.structure.postgresql.sql -F p -v -T public.* -T first_product.* -T second_product.* -T another_product.locales mydatabase
```

I need to exclude some schemas otherwise it would ended up on permissions or other errors. Even that I exclude schema public, it dumps all functions in that schema, like this:

```
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION gin_extract_trgm(text, internal) FROM PUBLIC;
psql:./data/base.structure.postgresql.sql:8482: ERROR:  function gin_extract_trgm(text, internal) does not exist
```

I know this comes from the fulltext or similarity plugin in PostgreSQL, but I don't use it and don't need it on my machine, so I'd like to exclude these functions.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to exclude some schemas

pg_dump has a switch to **exclude schemas**:

```
pg_dump -N schema ...
```

I quote [the manual about pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html):

> -N schema
>   --exclude-schema=schema
>
> Do not dump any schemas matching the schema pattern. The pattern is interpreted according to the same rules as for -n. -N can be given
>   more than once to exclude schemas matching any of several patterns.
>   ...

---

With **PostgreSQL 9.1** or later you have new options to move extensions into a separate schema - even pre-installed old-style modules. You can register old object with your (new-style) extension and then use the new tools. With `fulltext` and `similarity` you probably mean [`fuzzystrmatch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/fuzzystrmatch.html) and [`tsearch2`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tsearch2.html). Example:

Register existing old-style objects for the extension `fuzzystrmatch`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch SCHEMA public FROM unpackaged;
```

Drop the extension:

```
DROP EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

Install it to another schema:

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch SCHEMA my_schema;
```

Of course, you cannot drop the extension, if objects from it are in use.
Also, if you install to another schema, you need to schema-qualify its functions in use or add the schema to the [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to do it. Say your backup is named backup.dump. What you need to do is:

```
$ pg_restore -l -f out.txt backup.dump
```

That will create a file out.txt that contains a list of objects that are in the dump. You need to edit the file and delete the items you don't want restored. Then you do this:

```
$ pg_restore -L out.txt -h your.host.name -U username ....  backup.dump
```

This will use a file out.txt (that you edited) to select the things that will be restored. Pretty handy especially in case the dump is large and you cannot re-dump the database.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Bartosz above, you can use the following sed command to remove e.g. a certain FUNCTION from the list before restoring:

```
sed -r -i -e '/FUNCTION public plpgsql_call_handler\(\) postgres/d' /var/backup/${DBNAME}.list
```