# Symfony2 - Custom DQL Function Registered But Does Not Exist

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I am desperatelly trying to include the LEVENSHTEIN function in Symfony2, however, I still receive errors. Specs + what I've done so far:

- PostgreSQL 9.3
- LEVENSHTEIN included in fuzzystrmatch extension
- Tested the function via shell execution. Works perfectly fine:

  ```
  postgres=# SELECT levenshtein('test', 'text');
   levenshtein
  -------------
             1
  (1 row)
  ```
- Added the function in DQL:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace AppBundle\DQL;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

  class LevenshteinFunction extends FunctionNode {

      public $firstStringExpression = null;

      public $secondStringExpression = null;

      public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker) {
          return 'LEVENSHTEIN(' . $this->firstStringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' . $this->secondStringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
      }

      public function parse(Parser $parser) {
          // levenshtein(str1, str2)
          $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
          $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
          $this->firstStringExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
          $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
          $this->secondStringExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
          $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
      }
  }
  ```

  **Config.yml**

  ```
  orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
      auto_mapping: true
      dql:
          numeric_functions:
              LEVENSHTEIN: AppBundle\DQL\LevenshteinFunction
  ```
- **Problem**: When executing the following codeblock in my Repository, the following errors occur:

  ```
  $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT LEVENSHTEIN('test', 'text') FROM AppBundle:User");
  return $query->getResult();
  ```

  > SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function levenshtein(unknown, unknown) does not exist

What am I missing? Why isn't DQL/Symfony/PDO/... recognizing the function? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from Postgres, seems like a problem with visibility.

The additional module [`fuzzystrmatch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/fuzzystrmatch.html) has to be installed, of course. You obviously did that, or your function call would not work in psql either.

- [How to exclude PL/pgSQL functions in export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715434/how-to-exclude-pl-pgsql-functions-in-export/9715779#9715779)

If it works in psql, but not in your app, only a few possible explanations remain. The obvious first:

- You ***are*** connected to the same database? (Same server, same port, same db?)
- You are connecting with the same user? Probably *not* ...
- If connecting with a different user (but in any case), check whether you are working the same search path. Run in either connection and compare:

  ```
  SHOW search_path;
  ```

  Details - and how to set the `search_path`:

  - [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Be aware that extensions can be installed to any schema of your choice. Default is the first schema in the `search_path` (the "current schema" at the time of the install, which is typically `public`, but I don't know that about your installation. The documentation:

> If not specified, and the extension's control file does not specify a
>   schema either, the current default object creation schema is used.

Run this to diagnose a couple of things:

```
SELECT e.extname AS extension, nsp.nspname AS schema
     , r.rolname AS schema_owner, nsp.nspacl AS schema_acl
FROM   pg_extension e
JOIN   pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = e.extnamespace
JOIN   pg_roles     r   ON r.oid = nsp.nspowner
```

You get something like:

> ```
>    extension   |   schema   | schema_owner |             schema_acl
>
> ---------------+------------+--------------+-------------------------------------
>  adminpack     | pg_catalog | postgres     | {postgres=UC/postgres,=U/postgres}
>  plpgsql       | pg_catalog | postgres     | {postgres=UC/postgres,=U/postgres}
>  fuzzystrmatch | public     | postgres     | {postgres=UC/postgres,=UC/postgres}
>  tablefunc     | public     | postgres     | {postgres=UC/postgres,=UC/postgres}
>  ...
> ```

If `schema_acl` includes `=U/postgres` ([`U` for `USAGE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html##SQL-GRANT-NOTES)), then the `public` role has access, i.e. everybody.

Set the `search_path` for your connection accordingly or (re-)install to a visible schema and it should work.

*Theoretically*, the owning role or a superuser might have revoked the `EXECUTE` permission from the function itself ...

Answer (score 1):

Your function class seems ok to me, but your configuration might be wrong. This is what I have for my `CAST` function:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                CAST: App\MyBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Functions\Porgres\Cast
```

You should note that you have different collections for the different types of functions i.e. `string_functions`,`numeric_functions`, `datetime_functions`. All of them are listed in the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#full-default-configuration).

Other than that, your code should be working just fine after you clean your cache.